# UI Designer for JHipster?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, jhipster

I am new to JHipster. I generated an Angular 2 project using JHipster 4.5.1. It is an awesome experience!!

Now, I would like to modify the default JHipster generated Angular 2 pages and create custom pages.

I would like to know is there any UI designer/bootstrap builder available and work nicely with JHipster? Maybe tools like https://bootstrapstudio.io/, http://pingendo.com/ can be used? Any recommendations?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster 4.5.1 is using Bootstrap 4, so you can use the tools you mentioned to create the interface that suits your needs.

One warning however, be very careful about the bootstrap version mentioned in the tools you are using. Most of the time, migration between boostrap 3 and 4 can break a few things.

Another recommendation : Jhipster has the ability to use compiled css (If you activate it when generating the app), which can be a great way to put mutualize css ressources when needed, take a look at **sass** for more info.

One last piece of advice : css and html generators can make code pretty hard to read (Not all of them, it's up to you to define "hard to read" too), so I would advise using them wisely : take a few bits of code here and there and adapt it to your needs.

Hope this helps !
Enjoy Jhipster.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these instructions: https://jhipster.github.io/customizing-bootstrap-4/
I know, the page is light and should be improved.

Either, you can use the CSS from https://bootswatch.com/4-alpha/
It works very well ;-)